# Decrypt value of NameID (getAuthData('saml:sp:NameID')->value)

Tags: php, saml, simplesamlphp

I would like to retrieve the `NameID` used by the `IDP` in clear text, but with the `getAuthData` function, I get an encrypted value.

How to do?

Actually I can get attributes with :

```
require_once("pathlin");

$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp');

$attrs = $as->getAttributes();
```

Si I can parse the dictionary and get some attributes.

But now I want to get NameID, I try with :

```
$as->getAuthData("saml:sp:NameID")->value
```

authsource.php :

```
$config = [
'admin' => [
    'core:AdminPassword',
],
'example-userpass' => [
    'exampleauth:UserPass',
    'testuid:testtest' => [
        'uid' => ['testuid'],
    ],
],
```

];

saml20-idp-hosted.php :

```
$metadata['__DYNAMIC:1__'] = [
'host' => '__DEFAULT__',

'privatekey' => 'example.org.pem',
'certificate' => 'example.org.crt',

'auth' => 'example-userpass',
'attributes.NameFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri',
'authproc' => array(
  100 => array('class' => 'core:AttributeMap', 'name2oid'),
),];
```

config.php (authproc.idp) :

```
'authproc.idp' => [
  1 => array(
    'class' => 'saml:TransientNameID',
  ),
  2 => array(
      'class' => 'saml:PersistentNameID',
      'attribute' => 'eduPersonPrincipalName',
  ),
  3 => array(
      'class' => 'saml:AttributeNameID',
      'attribute' => 'mail',
      'Format' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',),],
```

So, how get 'testuid', by NameID ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried so far and what specific issues/errors you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Your IdP is not setting a NameID AND your SP isn't requesting a non-transient NameID. By default SSP will generate a transient NameID, which is just random, not an encrypted value.

To set a NameID in your test IDP you'll need an [authproc](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-authproc) filter to set the NameID. [AttributeNameID](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/saml:nameid) will let you set one from your attributes.
Lastly, you'll need either your SP to request that nameID in it's authn request (see [NameID policy](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/saml:nameid)) or ensure your SP metadata has the desired nameID format defined (by defining NameIDFormat in your SP authsource and reloading the metadata into the idp).

In the end it is usually much easier to just put the username in an attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, I edited my post with new information, if you have any other information given to me.

thank you in advance